# How to create controllers for views inside Ember.ContainerView?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For any view in Ember.js we need to create controller with appropriate name in order to use this controller, but this is not a case for views inside `ContainerView`.

View (inside ContainerView):

```
App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

Controller:

```
App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function () {
        alert('Hell no! I\'m not going to init!');
        return this._super();
    }
});
```

Above doesn't work...

Solution like `this.set('controller', App.ChildController.create())` (inside view) is not an option because `Ember.Evented`, `needs` and probably more stuff doesn't work.

**Here is the (not) working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wbednarski/XaPSR/**

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> For any view in Ember.js we need to create controller with appropriate name in order to use this controller

I'm not sure this premise is correct. ContainerView is a pretty low-level view library that does not know anything about controllers. It might be used to create small a widget or component, and in that case the child views would not have their own controllers. If you are looking to bind views inside ContainerView to their own controllers that is a sign that ContainerView is not a good fit for the problem you're trying to solve.

Instead, consider using handlebars helpers like `{{render}}` and `{{each}}`.

Comment: The question is more like why there is no controller. Look, when I have MVC trio `modelA`, `viewA`, `controllerA` and then embed `viewA` somewhere in the app my controller works fine, when embed `viewA` into `ContainerView` it does't - look at jsfiddle. Thanks for your time!

Comment: There is no controller because you didn't create one. So when you have MVC trio modelA, viewA, controllerA and `embed viewA somehow` it's controller may or may not work depending on how you embeded viewA. For sure if you use the view helper like `{{view App.ViewA}}` then controller will not be set to `controllerA`. If you use `{{render viewA}}` then it will.

Comment: If you really want to know how to associate childViews with controllers for a CollectionView read source code for the `{{each}}` helper. It defines `EachView` which extends `Ember.CollectionView` and `Ember.ContainerView`. It's initializer has logic that will associate child views with their own controller when the `itemController` property has been set. Check that out here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/each.js#L17-L37